# Matlab: too many input arguments to strcmp

Tags: matlab, strcmp

I have a data structure, and I'm trying to replace a char value within it.
I'm using the following code:
`raw(1,1).stimulus.values{1,1}.name=order{1};`

If I run either side of this on its own, I get a single string of class `char` in return.
`raw(1,1).stimulus.values{1,1}.name`

Returns:
`ans = 'stim_channel1'`

`order{1}` returns `ans = 'visff'`

But if I run the whole thing, I get the following error:

```
Error using strcmp
Too many input arguments.
Error in Dictionary/subsasgn (line 233)
                if strcmp(s.type,'()')
```

But I'm trying to replace a single string with another single string. How is this too many arguments?
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!
Matlab R2021b, if it matters.

Comment: What does your ```subj``` argument look like?

Comment: Sorry, should have subbed that out. It's just a `double` (in this case equals `1`). Replacing it with `1` doesn't make a difference.

I've edited the question.

Comment: What are the types and sizes of ```raw(1,1).stimulus``` and ```raw(1,1).stimulus.values{1,1}```?

Comment: The first is a dictionary, the latter is a custom data structure. Both 1x1.

Comment: You seem to use a class `Dictionary`, which I don’t know anything about, and which is throwing this error. Why make such a complex data structure, and why include a custom class inside it?

Comment: Do `which strcmp in Dictionary.subsasgn` in MATLAB, and see what it tells you. I expect this to be some custom function that is shadowing the builtin one.

Comment: It's using the builtin: `built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2021a.app/toolbox/matlab/strfun/strcmp)`

Comment: Oh, I see, `s` has more than one array element, so `s.type` is a comma-separated list of multiple values. Edric below is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the LHS alone, it uses the `subsref` method, which apparently can handle the multi-level indexing. However, it looks like the assignment method of that class `subsasgn` is not designed to handle multiple-level indexing.

You need either to fix `Dictionary/subsasgn`, or else split out the LHS so that you're doing only a simple assignment into the `Dictionary`.

Given that `raw(1,1).stimulus` is of the problematic `Dictionary` class, you need to ensure that you use on a single level of indexed assignment into that. In other words:

```
% Extract "values" from Dictionary
sv = raw(1,1).stimulus.values;
% Modify "values"
sv{1,1}.name = order{1};
% Put "values" back into Dictionary
raw(1,1).stimulus.values = sv;
```

Comment: Sorry for the noobish question, but how would I go about splitting out the LHS?
The `Dictionary` in question is a data structure used by a toolbox I'm using (although it's using the builtin `strcmp`), so I can't really go in and change it without fear of messing up other functionality...

Comment: I updated the answer with what I _think_ you need to do. But of course I can't try it out. Basically, this is a limitation of `Dictionary` - it handles only single-level indexed assignment operations, and your expression is a multi-level indexed assignment (i.e. it has more `{}` and `.field` stuff)

Comment: (And having written multiple implementations of `subsasgn`, I do sympathise with the author of `Dictionary`. It's a pain)